# MKMapView finding position and show it to the user

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview

[image]

I know position in the Rose pin called A and it is like in the picture... Now what I want to do is this.

When the user of my app is in the red circle with radius of 1km my app must say that he is at the Tour Eiffel.

How can I do that? I understand that I must retrieve the position but after that how can I look for a radius of 1 km from with center in the current position?
Thanks

*** EDIT *** 
Thank you I'm using

```
 if ([region containsCoordinate:self.map.userLocation.coordinate]) {
                    miTrovoIn = street;
                }
```

But if I don't show my position in the map this code doesn't work.
If I check my position and than share my position it works.
How can I force the app to get automatically my position without the interaction of the user?
Thanks

Comment: This sort of feature is called geo-fencing. Search around for tutorials on that and you're bound to find one you can work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a CLRegion. 
From docs:

`The CLRegion class defines a geographical area that can be tracked. When an instance of this class is registered with a CLLocationManager object, the location manager generates an appropriate event whenever the user crosses the boundaries of the defined area.`

Set the properties for center and radius to your desired values. Call startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy. If you need to test the location of the user rather than use the notification generated when the user crosses the boundary of your defined region, there is a containsCoordinate: instance method for the CLRegion class.

```
double lat = 48.86;
double lng = 2.29;
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng);
CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centerCoordinate radius:1000.0 identifier:@"your identifier"];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: mmm can you suggest me a tutorial? I can't understand how I must Set the properties for center and radius!

Comment: Thank you I solved my problem but I have another small problem... can you help me? see my edit... thanks again